# How to make a forecast using TVP VAR model in statsmodels?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I repeated the TVP VAR model from the tutorial article https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_tvpvar_mcmc_cfa.html
But now I would like to make a forecast and some kind of summary of the coefficients for the last date. But I can't use the Forecast, Predict, Fit methods, nothing works.

Is there any way to make a prediction?